# Update text label when UICollectionView cell is presented

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` (A), where I can scroll between different cells horizontally, which is itself in a `CollectionViewCell` (B).

I am defining some layout in the `CollectionViewCell` (B) and would like one text label to be updated when a certain cell in (A) is presented.

**What I have, in (B)**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: friendRequestCellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendRequestCell

    cell.user = userFriendRequests?[indexPath.row]
    nameLabel.text = cell.user?.first_name

    return cell
}
```

**Issue**

The text in the `nameLabel` gets populated incorrectly with the `user.first_name` as it does not update suitably when scrolling through the cells in (A), i.e. the cell presented in (A) and the `user.first_name` displayed in (B) often don't match. I am pretty sure doing it like this just updates the text when the cells in (A) get dequeued, which is of course not what I want.

What could be the correct way to implement the desired behavior ?

**EDIT**

Found out about the nifty `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` method which almost solves the problem, but this changes the label as soon as the next cell starts to display. This means that when the Collection View is loaded, if I scroll just a bit forth and back, the `nameLabel` contains the `firstName + " " + lastName` of the second cell while the first one is displayed. Looking for some kind of "didDisplay" method but haven't found something like it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let firstName = userFriendRequests?[indexPath.row].first_name, let lastName = userFriendRequests?[indexPath.row].last_name else {
        return
    }

    nameLabel.text = firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

PS: Still a Swift noob, also thought about using some kind of delegation but a bit unclear on how that would play out in this case

Comment: UICollectionView is UIScrollView. If what you are doing with this label is dependent upon how the collection view is scrolled, why not implement UIScrollViewDelegate? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll

Comment: Hey @matt, what I am doing is dependent on which cell is currently "displayed". My `CollectionViewCells` are created from a datasource which is an array of `User`, each having properties like `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. The cells each take up the full size of the CollectionView's frame, with a horizontal scrolling and pagination enabled to make scrolling smooth. I want to change the label's content with the `first_name` and `last_name` property of the cell when it is currently displayed in full in the CollectionView's frame (i.e. when the pagination to the next cell has been performed)